# Executing a PHP script in CentOS using Crontab

Tags: php, cron, centos8

I am trying to run a Cron job which executes a PHP script in CentOS 8 by using Crontab, but for some reason it is now working.

This is my cron task:

```
* * * * * root /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite.net/html/application/crons/update.php
```

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php
     // Update cron
     $test = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=SERVERIP;Database=DB", "usr", "pass");

     $update = $test->prepare("UPDATE table SET Change = 0, Counter = 0");
     $update->execute();

?>
```

I also added `> result.log` at the end of the Cron task to see if it logged something, but this file is empty. Not sure what's happening.

Right now is set to run every minute, but no changes are being made in the SQL Server database

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

My environment is the following:

- CentOS 8
- PHP 7.4 (Remi Package)
- httpd
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express

Comment: `>` only redirects STDOUT, `&>` redirects STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Ohh, I see, now I am having this error `/bin/sh: root: command not found`

Comment: Omg, yeah that was the problem. I deleted the `root` from the beginning of the task and now it is working. I just needed to log the error. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Yeah the user specification is only necessary in system-level crontabs, [eg: `/etc/cron.d/foo`] and I'm assuming that this was created in a user's personal crontab. [eg: `crontab -e`] Also, don't run anything as root that you don't _absolutely_ have to.

Comment: Yeah I am using `crontab -e`. Thanks for your information, really appreciate it.